# All Qt GUI applications hang up trying to open or save a file

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, gui, qt

I use Mint Linux 20.3 on my office workstation, with a custom Qt 5.15.6 build, Qt Creator, and TeXStudio. Some side applications, like the VLC Media Player I use, are also compiled with this Qt build. Since some moment in the past, all GUI applications based on Qt in my system started hanging up deadly when I tried to open a file from GUI. From the CLI everything works fine. The identical problem also comes with the Telegram Desktop app which hangs up when I order to save a file, but in a difference with other Qt applications, this happens after the save dialog is closed. I do not see anything wrong in the debugger, logs, etc. to cope with this problem.

Could you please point me to some method on how to solve this problem? I guess it would be unexpected awaiting operation for some resource but I have no clue where to find and configure this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I stacktraced one of my Qt applications, having this very weird result (the output was consumed by these long strings):

```
access("//home/twdragon/\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202
\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302
\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202
\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303
\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203
\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302
\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203
\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303
\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202
\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302
\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202
\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303
\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203
\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302
\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202
\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303
\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202
\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302
\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203
\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303
\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203
\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302
\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203
\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303
\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202
\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302
\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203
\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303
\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203
\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302
\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202
\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303
\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202
\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302
\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203
\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303
\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203
\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302
\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203
\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303
\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202
\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302
\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202
\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303
\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203
\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302
\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202
\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303
\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202
\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302
\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202
\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303
\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203
\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302
\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203
\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303
\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202
\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302
\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203
\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303
\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203
\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302
\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202
\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303
\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202
\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302
\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202
\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303
\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203
\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302
\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203
\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303
\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202
\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302
\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202
\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303
\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203
\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302
\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202
\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303
\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202
\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302
\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202
\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303
\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203
\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302
\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203
\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303
\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202
\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302
\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203
\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303
\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203
\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302
\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202
\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303
\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202
\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302
\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203
\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303
\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203
\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302
\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203
\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303
\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202
\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302
\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202
\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303
\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203
\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302
\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202
\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303
\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202
\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302
\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203
\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303
\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203
\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302
\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203
\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303
\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202
\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302
\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203
\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303
\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203
\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302
\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202
\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303
\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202
\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302
\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202
\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303
\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203
\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302
\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203
\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303
\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202
\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302
\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202
\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303
\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203
\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302
\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202
\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303
\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202
\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302
\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202
\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303
\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203
\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302
\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203
\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303
\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202
\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302
\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203
\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303
\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203
\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302
\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202
\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303
\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202
\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302
\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203
\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303
\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203
\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302
\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203
\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303
\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202
\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302
\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202
\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303
\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203
\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302
\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202
\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303
\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202
\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302
\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202
\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303
\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203
\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302
\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203
\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303
\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202
\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302
\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203
\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303
\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203
\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302
\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202
\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303
\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202
\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302
\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202
\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303
\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203
\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302
\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203
\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303
\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202
\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302
\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202
\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303
\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203
\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302
\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202
\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303
\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202
\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302
\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202
\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303
\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203
\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302
\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203
\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303
\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202
\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302
\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203
\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303
\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203
\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302
\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202
\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303
\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202
\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302
\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203
\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303
\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203
\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302
\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203
\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303
\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202
\302\202\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302
\203\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202
\303\203\302\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303
\203\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203
\302\202\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302
\202\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\202
\303\202\302\202\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\203\303\203\302\202\303
\202\302"..., F_OK) = -1 ENAMETOOLONG
```

After the investigation of my Cinnamon installation, I discovered that the file `~/.config/QtProject.conf` stored a lot of entries like `file://home/twdragon/\303\203\302\203\303...` in the `history` field, and the size of the whole file became more than 6 MB(!). This provoked some kind of undefined behaviour in `QFileDialog` leaving it waiting for the access confirmation of these fake filenames forever. After I had cleaned up the configuration file, everything started working again.